# With the Simplenews module, how can I use a custom mytheme/node--type.tpl.php with emails?

Tags: theming, emails

With the Simplenews module, how can I use a custom mytheme/node--type.tpl.php with emails?

Comment: The template file in The simplenews module is simplenews/theme/simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php. so try with that name instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, since the Simplenews module is using the [simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/theme!simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php/7-1) template file ([this file](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!simplenews!theme!simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php/6), in case you are using Drupal 6). The Drupal 7 template file is described as follows:

> Copy this file in your theme directory to create a custom themed body. Rename it to override it. Available templates: simplenews-newsletter-body--[tid].tpl.php simplenews-newsletter-body--[view mode].tpl.php simplenews-newsletter-body--[tid]--[view mode].tpl.php See [README.txt](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/README.txt/7-1) for more details.

Before Drupal 8, Drupal doesn't have the concept of including a template file from another one, so you can just copy the relevant parts of the template file inside another one, and adapt it basing on the variables the new template file gets.